# phonegap / cordova with jquery mobile localStorage sometime got undefined value

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm in developing Phonegap / Cordova with JQuery Mobile application for Android and IOS, and I want to store some user preference with localStorage.

let's say 'alerts', the values is 'true' or 'false' (true if the user want alert and false for the opposite).

so, when the device is ready I check if the localStorage.alerts is === undefine and if yes I init the localStorage.alerts with true.

e.g.

```
if (window.localStorage.alerts === undefined) {
         window.localStorage.alerts = 'true';
     }
```

in the setting page when user check or uncheck checkbox for this setting I set the value of the localStorage.alerts to 'true' or 'false'.

e.g. `window.localStorage.alerts = (this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');`

The problem is when the user quit from the application and start it again, sometimes I got undefine again even I init it in the first run time.

I'm using Cordova 3.4 and I test it right now on emulator run Android 4.1.2.

what wrong, please help.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="alerts" onchange="window.localStorage.alerts = (this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');" />
```

script:

```
receivedEvent: function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('alerts: ' + localStorage.alerts);

        if (localStorage.alerts === undefined) localStorage.alerts = 'true';
}
```

thanks,

Comment: any idea???, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,first get the value of `alert` using this

```
   //check alert is empty
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('alert')==null){
    //set alert to true value
    window.localStorage.setItem('alert',true);


    }
```

Also if localStorage item is not defined its default value is `null`.The same is using in settings page

```
 //if checkbox is checked 
    if(cheked){
     window.localStorage.setItem('alert',true);
    }else{
    //not checked
     window.localStorage.setItem('alert',false);
    }
```

Comment: 1st thanks for your help, you mean window.localStorage.setItem('alert','true') not window.localStorage.setItem('alert',**true**)

Comment: Its the correct way`window.localStorage.setItem('alert',true)`.

Comment: already check it and now check it again but now I got sometimes null

Comment: Also you can check `if(window.localStorage.getItem('alert')){ 
//localstorageitem is set
}else{
//not set,item value is null

}`

Comment: yes true is boolean if you want to store string put in it in single quotes,like this `//set alert to true boolean value
window.localStorage.setItem('alert',true);
//set alert to true as string value
window.localStorage.setItem('alert','true');`

Comment: good to know, I thought only string. anway as I said I check it and I got sometimes null

Comment: It's look like I'm request the values to early but I do that in the device is ready event

Comment: Are you tested in emulator or phone?if in emulator may be not working as we excepted ,so test in device

Comment: test it now on my android 4.0.4, same problem.

Comment: Right now I can't upload the code. I will upload it next week if you want.

Comment: FYI edit my question and add the relevant code as you request.